# Use generics and polymorphism to enhance C# code

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class `Deck` that handles `Card`s used in a game.

This is the base abstract `Card` class, it just defines each card value (`int`):

```
public abstract class Card
    {
        private int value;
        protected Card(int newValue)
        {
            this.value = newValue;
        }
        public int getValue() => value;

        public void setValue(int n)
        {
            value = n;
            return;
        }

    }
```

Some Card implementations:

Club

```
 public class Club : Card
    {
        public Club(int newValue) : base(newValue)
        {
        }
    }
```

Diamond

```
public class Diamond : Card
    {
        public Diamond(int newValue) : base(newValue)
        {
        }
    }
```

Heart

```
public class Heart : Card

{
    public Heart(int newValue) : base(newValue)
    {
    }
}
```

Spike

```
public class Spike : Card
    {
        public Spike(int newValue) : base(newValue)
        {
        }
    }
```

Now I want 10 `Card`s of each kind inside `Deck` for a total amount of 40 `Card`s (10 `Heart`, 10 `Spikes`...)

So I'm using this code inside `Deck` class:

```
public class Deck
    {
        List<Card> cards;
        public Deck() {
            cards = new List<Card>();
            populate();
        }
        void populate()
        {
            for(int i=1;i==10;i++)
                cards.Add(new Club(i));
            for (int i = 1; i == 10; i++)
                cards.Add(new Heart(i));
            for (int i = 1; i == 10; i++)
                cards.Add(new Spike(i));
            for (int i = 1; i == 10; i++)
                cards.Add(new Diamond(i));
        }
    }
```

It works but I want something like:

```
void populate(){
    [Heart,Spike,Club,Diamond].foreach((e) -> cards.add(e.generateTen()))
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way to write it, please read it as pseudocode I'm new in C# thanks for yourhelp.

Comment: Side note: C# is not Java - please use properties instead of getXxxx/setXxxx methods.

Comment: You definitely do not need different classes for each card suit.  And trying to design polymorphism where is not needed is really a bad idea. Also generics has nothing to do with what your are showing here.

Comment: This is a poor usage of polymorphism, by the way. All implementations have the same behaviour, only differing by their value. `Card` might as well not be abstract, you'd save yourself a lot of trouble then.

Comment: `public enum Suit { Club, Diamond, Heart, Spade } public class Card { public Suit Suit { get; set; } public int Value { get; set; } }`. This is how it should be done.

Comment: Note that in C# to create an array on the fly like `[Heart,Spike,Club,Diamond]` you need the `new` keyword, and you need to specify the array type. In the code above you have not described what each of Heart,Spike,Club,Diamond is? Are they primitives, classes or something else?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou these 4 are classes, you can read from above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, prefer composition to polymorphism. Here, all card implementations behave the same. If all subclasses of an abstract base class differ only by their constructor, then maybe that base class doesn't need to be abstract.

Instead, I would recommend a different approach. The suit of a card should be an enum, and then you can do things like:

```
public enum Suit
{
    Heart,
    Spike,
    Club,
    Diamond
}

public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Since `Suit` is now an enum, you can get an array of all suits with `Enum.GetValues()`, so to create the deck:

```
var deck = new List<Card>();
foreach(var suit in Enum.GetValues<Suit>())
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        deck.Add(new Card { Suit = suit, Value = i });
}
```

Or, if you want to get really fancy with LINQ:

```
var deck = (from suit in Enum.GetValues<Suit>()
           from value in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
           select new Card { Suit = suit, Value = value }).ToList();
```

---

If you really want to use polymorphism here, using the class hierarchy described in your question, to avoid duplicating the loops, you can either do an array of factory callbacks:

```
var factories = new Func<int, Card>[]
{
    i => new Heart(i),
    i => new Spike(i),
    i => new Club(i),
    i => new Diamond(i)
};
var deck = new List<Card>();
foreach(var factory in factories)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        var card = factory(i);
        deck.Add(card);
    }
}
```

Or you can use reflection, which is slightly less typing, but you lose type safety.

```
var suitTypes = new[] { typeof(Heart), typeof(Spike), typeof(Club), typeof(Diamond) };
var deck = new List<Card>();
foreach(var suitType in suitTypes)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        var card = (Card)Activator.CreateInstance(suitType, i);
        deck.Add(card);
    }
}
```

Most notably, if you don't have the same constructor signature everywhere, you won't notice until you run the program and get an exception. In general, you should always choose designs that make errors appear as early as possible, which is why I really don't recommend reflection based approaches unless absolutely required.

Comment: You're right, at the beginning I thought "Oh maybe this could be resolved through enum...Naaah let's use poly to try something different". Can you suggest me, if it doesn't bother you, a variation for poly?

Comment: I've added additional potential approaches using polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Array of factory functions would do:

```
var cards = (new Func<int, Card>[] {
    v => new Heart(v), 
    v => new Spike(v) })
    .Select(f => new {f, values = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)})
    .SelectMany(x => x.values.Select(v => x.f(v))).ToList();
```

Note that for decks of cards you would likely not use that and simply have suite as property (as it is extremally unlikely different suits will have different behaviors).

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can define `enum` values that are named constants that can take a limited range of values. A card can contain two such enums. One for the card suit, and one for the value.

```
public enum CardSuit
{
    Heart = 1,
    Spike,
    Club,
    Diamond,
}
public enum CardValue
{
    Ace = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
}

public class Card
{
    public Card(CardSuit suit, CardValue value)
    {
        Suit = suit;
        Value = value;
    }

    public CardSuit Suit { get; }
    public CardValue Value { get; }
    public int ValueInteger { get => (int)Value; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{Value} {Suit}]";
    }
}
```

Notice also the use of properties to store the values, and that they are readonly as the card value isn't going to change once it is defined.

Now define a deck of cards, with 10 cards (Ace through Ten) for each suit.

```
public class Deck
{
    readonly List<Card> cards;

    public Deck()
    {
        this.cards = new List<Card>();

        CardSuit[] all = new CardSuit[] {
            CardSuit.Heart,
            CardSuit.Spike,
            CardSuit.Club,
            CardSuit.Diamond };

        // alternatives for Framework and NET Core
        // var all = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardSuit)) as CardSuit[]
        // var all = Enum.GetValues<CardSuit>();
        
        foreach (CardSuit suit in all)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                CardValue value = (CardValue)(i + 1);
                cards.Add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Card> Cards => cards;
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var deck = new Deck();
        foreach (var card in deck.Cards)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card);
        }
    }
}
```

with the output

```text
[Two Heart]
[Three Heart]
[Four Heart]
[Five Heart]
[Six Heart]
[Seven Heart]
[Eight Heart]
[Nine Heart]
[Ten Heart]
[Ace Spike]
[Two Spike]
[Three Spike]
[Four Spike]
[Five Spike]
[Six Spike]
[Seven Spike]
[Eight Spike]
[Nine Spike]
[Ten Spike]
[Ace Club]
[Two Club]
[Three Club]
[Four Club]
[Five Club]
[Six Club]
[Seven Club]
[Eight Club]
[Nine Club]
[Ten Club]
[Ace Diamond]
[Two Diamond]
[Three Diamond]
[Four Diamond]
[Five Diamond]
[Six Diamond]
[Seven Diamond]
[Eight Diamond]
[Nine Diamond]
[Ten Diamond]
```